# Save variable from remote server using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, http-proxy

I have seen a couple of other threads relatively similar but I still find my problem unique so I hope you guys give me a chance.

What I want to do: use proxy to bypass same origin policy and to save these values (that changes and need to be checked by timer) into variables that can be modified.

A server contains data.asp which looks something like this and updates from time to time (although with a bit more data):

```
{ "Title":"Tile of song" ,"Artist":"The artist" ,"Album":"The album" ,"CDCover":"/covers/randomcover.jpg" }
```

The method I have tried is like the one on http://qnimate.com/same-origin-policy-in-nutshell/#Same_Origin_Policy_for_AJAX. In case you guys don't want to follow the link I've posted the data here as well.

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.qnimate.com/ajaxdata.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Request data</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

And the proxy file:

```
<?php
   echo file_get_contents('http://www.qscutter.com/ajaxdata.txt');
?>
```

So what I want to do is store the data into variables that I can alter, not show it inside a div using innerHTML. Preferably check this ever so often for changes as well.

Suggestions?

I can add that I have the permission from the server owner to retrieve the information and to use it but no possibility to add script to their server, hence the proxy bypass attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving the data in the JSON-format?

`{ "Title":"Tile of song" ,"Artist":"The artist" ,"Album":"The album" ,"CDCover":"/covers/randomcover.jpg" }`

To load this in a var you need `JSON.parse`.

For example

```
var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

When parsed through this function the object `data` contains the properties `title`, `artist`, `album` and `CDcover`.

Now you can modify the object

```
data['title'] = "I'll Be There This Christmas";
data['artist'] = "Gary Fomdeck";
//etc.
```

Please read introductions to [JSON](http://json.org/).